# ffmpeg usage to encode a video to H264 codec format

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I have a *.mp4 video file(MPEG4 video codec) and I am trying to convert this to a H264 video codec format(raw h.264 format) using ffmpeg on Linux(Version - FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.1-4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard,) using command line as shown below,

```
ffmpeg -i input .mp4 output.h264
```

but I get an error saying -

```
Unsupported codec for output stream #0.0
```

Then when i try this option:

```
ffmpeg -i input .mp4 -formats h264 output.h264
```

it still does not work, and gives -

```
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 59.94 (5994/100) -> 29.97 (30000/1001)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Rapture.mp4':
  Duration: 00:02:06.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 26574 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1920x1080, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16
```

And then it prints out help on the formats which we get when we do `ffmpeg -formats`

When I checked the help, `ffmpeg -formats`, I see below information related to H264 file format and codec:

```
File format : 

DE h264            raw H.264 video format

Codecs:

D V D  h264         H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
```

My questions :

1. How can I convert the video to a H264 encoded video (raw H264 video format)
2. When I do `ffmpeg -formats`, I see many acronyms for the codecs supported, I see many acronyms before the codec name/type such as - D V D S E A, what do they stand for?
3. How to use the ffmpeg options `-vcodec` and `-formats`?

Comment: D..... = Decoding supported
.E.... = Encoding supported
..V... = Video codec
..A... = Audio codec
..S... = Subtitle codec
...S.. = Supports draw_horiz_band
....D. = Supports direct rendering method 1
.....T = Supports weird frame truncation                                                      ; use ffmpeg -codecs

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I believe you have `libx264` installed and configured with `ffmpeg` to convert video to `h264`... Then you can try with `-vcodec libx264`... The `-format` option is for showing available formats, this is not a conversion option I think...

Comment: I have x264 installed on this linux machine, but when I use -vcodec libx264, it gives error "Unknown encoder 'libx264' " . I guess when I installed x264 , libx264 would also have been installed. Am i right. Also what configuration is needed to use libx264 to use with ffmpeg. How to configure ffmpeg which is already installed to use this libx264?

Comment: Hi, have a look at here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095 . During configuration of ffmpeg you have to enable libx264 codec using --enable libx264 option

Comment: That page says, If I have ffmpeg installed previously, I need to remove/uninstall , then build the libx264 and ffmpeg from source. I can do that, but isn't there any 'easier' way to install libx264 using the ubuntu pacgae manager/install apt-get install <libx264 something>..

Comment: @goldenman: I tried to use libx264 once with already installed ffmpeg, but I could not. I think ffmpeg puts only those codecs information in libavcodec that have been configured using --enable option. btw libx264 does not give much trouble installing from source :)...So better to configure and make ffmpeg newly with libx264

Comment: Great Ubuntu installation guide https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide

Answer (score 110):

Long story short:

`ffmpeg -i input.flv -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac output.mp4`

As @LordNeckbeard mentioned, you need to use the `libx264` encoder to produce the proper video with **H.264/AAC**. To test the output file you can just drag it to a browser window and it should playback just fine.

Comment: when i use -vcodec mpeg4, browser only runs audio not video

Comment: @Salmaan you might not have the video codec on the system, you might want to try `ffmpeg -codecs` to see what you have available

Comment: @Salmaan That's because mpeg4 is not h.264/AVC.

Comment: **This does not output H.264 video.** Using `mpeg4` produces the old, legacy MPEG-4 Part 2 video, not H.264 video. This will not work in HTML5 video. Change `mpeg4` to `libx264` to encode H.264 video.

Comment: Adding `-movflags +faststart` is recommended for HTML5 playback (and all other progressive download playback) so it can begin playing before the file is completely downloaded by the viewer.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that by now the above answers are outdated (or at least unclear) so here's my little go at it.
I tried compiling ffmpeg with the option `--enable-encoders=libx264` and it will give no error but it won't enable anything (I can't seem to find where I found that suggestion).

Anyways step-by-step, first you must compile libx264 yourself because repository version is outdated:

```
  wget ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/x264/snapshots/last_x264.tar.bz2
  tar --bzip2 -xvf last_x264.tar.bz2
  cd x264-snapshot-XXXXXXXX-XXXX/
  ./configure
  make
  sudo make install
```

And then get and compile ffmpeg with libx264 enabled.
I'm using the latest release which is "Happiness":

```
wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-0.11.2.tar.bz2
tar --bzip2 -xvf ffmpeg-0.11.2.tar.bz2
cd ffmpeg-0.11.2/
./configure --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl
make
sudo install
```

Now finally you have the libx264 codec to encode, to check it you may run

```
ffmpeg -codecs | grep h264
```

and you'll see the options you have were the first D means decoding and the first E means encoding

Comment: I found that make install for libx264 installed only the executable x264 program, but not the libraries. After I used install-lib-dev install-lib-shared and install-lib-static it worked fine (I'm not sure which of these is necessary but I succeeded with all three).

Comment: If i'm going to compile ffmpeg for ARM processors, should I compile libx264 same as ffmpeg?! (do some specific stuff for libx264 too?).

Answer (score 3):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpegX86shared\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -y -i "C:\testfile.ts" -an -vcodec libx264 -g 75 -keyint_min 12 -vb 4000k -vprofile high -level 40 -s 1920x1080 -y -threads 0 -r 25 "C:\testfile.h264"
```

The above worked for me on a Windows machine using a FFmpeg Win32 shared build by Kyle Schwarz. The build was compiled on: Feb 22 2013, at: 01:09:53

Note that -an defines that audio should be skipped.

Answer (score -3):

I have a Centos 5 system that I wasn't able to get this working on.  So I built a new Fedora 17 system (actually a VM in VMware), and followed the steps at [the ffmpeg site](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide) to build the latest and greatest ffmpeg.

I took some shortcuts - I skipped all the yum erase commands, added freshrpms according to their instructions:

```
wget http://ftp.freshrpms.net/pub/freshrpms/fedora/linux/9/freshrpms-release/freshrpms-release-1.1-1.fc.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm
```

Then I loaded the stuff that was already readily available:

```
yum install lame libogg libtheora libvorbis lame-devel libtheora-devel
```

Afterwards, I only built the following from scratch:  libvpx  vo-aacenc-0.1.2 x264  yasm-1.2.0 ffmpeg

Then this command encoded with no problems (the audio was already in AAC, so I didn't recode it):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

The result looks just as good as the original to me, and is about 1/4 of the size!

Comment: Please edit your answer `sameq` is not what you want (See ffmpeg FAQ 3.17 Why was the ffmpeg -sameq option removed? What to use instead?)

Comment: Thanks malat - I've been wasting options all this time.